# Reference request for "Divisibility of certain arithmetic functions" by Serre

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

The paper mentioned in the title can be found [here](http://www.numdam.org/article/SDPP_1974-1975__16_1_A15_0.pdf). My problem is that it is in french and my French is only as good as Google Translate. Is there any english translations out there or is there any expository material discussing the results of that paper. The paper is classic and the result is well known in number theory.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: "My French is only as good as Google Translate" I have not encountered many papers where Google Translate is not sufficient to understand the meaning. What parts, exactly, are you struggling to understand? Do you have an example of a sentence that GT does not make you understand? You might also want to try [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator).

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Using GT to each and every line/ sentence is extremely tedious specially when we have mathematical expressions in between. In that paper, I am interested in Theorem 4.7 (i). In that statement, I want to know if the constant implied in the O(.) is dependent on the level/weight of the form and I want to know if the result holds for arbitrary character as well. Both of these are not clearly mentioned in the theorem or in the preceding paragraph (i.e. as far as I could understand). So, I thought if I could understand the proof, then I could answer these questions for myse